# Create a new branch on remote and local as Dev

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch

Step 1: I cloned the `master` into my local

Step 2: Then I have merged another branch to master on local like this:

```
git fetch origin other-branch

git merge origin/other-branch
```

Step 3: Now I need to create a new branch on remote and local as `Dev` after `step 2`.How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply checkout a new branch called `Dev` and push the branch to remote.

```
$ git checkout -b Dev      # Create lcoal 'Dev' branch and checkout to that branch  
$ git push -u origin Dev
```

Comment: Hope I have to create new branch manually on Git as `Dev` before this command `git checkout -b Dev` no?

Comment: `git checkout -b Dev` create a new branch `Dev` and checkout to that branch (`-b` is the trick)

Comment: Oh..Great.Hope now I'm in `master` after the `step 2` no (on my post's steps)?

Comment: Yes, after step 2 you are in `master` branch.